# AutoHotKey | Mouse sensetivity changing script

Tags: autohotkey

I have a script to slow down mouse movement on button hold:

```
XButton2::
DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", UInt, 0x71, UInt, 0, UInt, 3, UInt, 0)
KeyWait XButton2
return 

XButton2 up::DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", UInt, 0x71, UInt, 0, UInt, 10, UInt, 0)

^+!0::
Exit
```

My problem is that when holding down shift or ctrl the script won't work.
Also, It doesn't work in games. And seriousley messes up windows when holding other keys.
Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the hotkey to fire even if the modifiers are being held down use the `*` modifier:

```
*XButton2::
```

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea on how to make it work in games and not drive my windows nuts?

Comment: @user2960343 I would suggest you avoid dll calls, and find a pure autohotkey solution. Please consider  accepting this answer (green checkmark to the left) if you found it useful.